# Create Matrix from values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

I have a list of indices/values that looks like this:

```
19, 11, 43
19, 12, 23
19, 13, 2
19, 14, 90
20, 11, 12
20, 12, 0
20, 13, 98
20, 14, 2
21, 11, 43
21, 12, 8
21, 13, 55
21, 14, 34
```

I need a method, preferably using Python, that transforms it into a `i x j` matrix using column1 and column2 as `i & j` indices, while values inside matrix correspond to column3, so the result looks like this:

```
     11  12  13  14
19   43  23  2   90
20   12  0   98  2
21   43  8   55  34
```

Can anyone give me advice on how to achieve this?

Comment: You can't just expect people to do your work for you. Show your work - what have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: Thank you for your helpfull comment. I've been struggling to find a way to handle this but can't figure out a way, and none of the solutions I've found in stackoverflow or elsewhere seem to fit my case.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you can use pandas, becuase if you can, this is very straight forward:

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(data_file, header=None, names=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
print(df)

pivot = df.pivot(index='col1', columns='col2', values='col3')
print(pivot)
```

**Test Data:**

```
from io import StringIO
data_file = StringIO(u'\n'.join([x.strip() for x in """
    19, 11, 43
    19, 12, 23
    19, 13, 2
    19, 14, 90
    20, 11, 12
    20, 12, 0
    20, 13, 98
    20, 14, 2
    21, 11, 43
    21, 12, 8
    21, 13, 55
    21, 14, 34
""".split('\n')[1:-1]]))
```

**Results:**

```
    col1  col2  col3
0     19    11    43
1     19    12    23
2     19    13     2
3     19    14    90
4     20    11    12
5     20    12     0
6     20    13    98
7     20    14     2
8     21    11    43
9     21    12     8
10    21    13    55
11    21    14    34

col2  11  12  13  14
col1                
19    43  23   2  90
20    12   0  98   2
21    43   8  55  34
```

Answer (score 0):

The question needs clarification what data structure should host the result. 
You could work with nested core data structure, however, usually it is done with pandas or numpy.

My solution with numpy

```
import numpy as np

text="""19, 11, 43
19, 12, 23
19, 13, 2
19, 14, 90
20, 11, 12
20, 12, 0
20, 13, 98
20, 14, 2
21, 11, 43
21, 12, 8
21, 13, 55
21, 14, 34"""

A_import=np.matrix(text.replace('\n',';')) 
A=A_import[:,2].reshape(3,4)
A
```

returns an numpy matrix object

```
matrix([[43, 23,  2, 90],
       [12,  0, 98,  2],
       [43,  8, 55, 34]])
```

(I have read the question in the way that you care in particular about the matrix, so I have omitted the indices.)